# how to fetch object array from node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i am creating a simple todo app using React js and node ,how to fetch object array(task list) from node to react for display that list at the time of button click

```
  const lists =[
    {toDo:"learn react"}
  ]
  app.post('/Todo',function(req, res){
    lists.push({ "toDo":req.body.list})
    console.log(lists)
    res.status(200).send({ message: "Task added!!"})
  }
)
```

```
  axios.post('http://localhost:8080/Todo',request)
        .then(resp=>{
            alert(resp.data.message);
        })
        .catch( err=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
  }

  return (
      <div >
        <h1>ToDo List</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder=" Add item..." name="list" value={toDos} onChange={(e)=>setToDos(e.target.value)}/>
        <button id="btn" type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Todo;
```

How can I fetch the array to react page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data from the response in state. The empty array in the useState is initially empty. However, once the axios call has been made and returned some data, the useEffect function will be called and cause the task list array to be populated. The result of which can then be iterated over and displayed on the front end.

```
let taskList = axios.post('http://localhost:8080/Todo',request)
    .then(resp=>{
        alert(resp.data.message);
    })
    .catch( err=>{
        console.log(err);
    })


const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setTasks(taskList);
}, [taskList]);


    return (

        <div >
        <h1>ToDo List</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" placeholder=" Add item..." name="list" value={toDos} onChange={(e)=>setToDos(e.target.value)}/>
            {tasks.map(() => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1>{tasks}</h1>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            <button id="btn" type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    );
}


export default Todo;
```

Comment: used this code but an error  Line 32:16:  'tasks' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

ERROR in [eslint]
src\Todoapp\Todo.js
  Line 45:10:  'task' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 48:20:  'tasks' is not defined  no-undef